# Two modules requiring different versions of angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my application ionic requires angular version to be 1.5.3 and angular-ui-calendar needs the version to be ~1.4.x .

Since i cannot install 1.4.x version of angular on my machine due to ionic dependency i am getting the following error in calendar.js

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: You have 2 options. Downgrade your ionic version or use other calendar that support angular 1.5.3 above. Cheers